# Last row of 2-dimensions array only retrieved

Tags: javascript, jquery

The array slidesArray is two-dimensional array. It is filled with 2 rows. The problem is that it get only the last row when try to use (each) function on jQuery.

Here is the code :

```
jQuery.each(slidesArray,function(index,value) {
    $("#slider").show();

    var linkHref = value[1];
    var imageSource = value[0];;

    $("#slider").html(
        "<a href='" + linkHref + "'><img src='"+ imageSource + "'></a>")
        .fadeOut(5000);
});
```

So, What's the problem or the causes ?

Comment: can you show your array?

Comment: [0,0] = "web.php" [0,1] = "web.jpg" [1,0] = "hosting.php" [1,1] = "hosting.jpg"

Comment: `.html()` will replace every thing in `$("#slider")` so only the last will remain

Comment: you have to add/append the previous content as well...

Comment: @Musa , I know, but it should waits on the first iteration , because it takes a time to fadeOut. This is not happened !

Answer (score 1):

correct this

```
 $("#slider").html
            (
                "<a href='" + linkHref + "'><img src='"+ imageSource + "'></a>"
            ).fadeOut(5000);
```

to

```
 $("#slider").html
            ($("#slider").html()+
                "<a href='" + linkHref + "'><img src='"+ imageSource + "'></a>"
            ).fadeOut(5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#slider").append("<a href='" + linkHref + "'><img src='"+ imageSource + "'></a>").fadeOut(5000);
```

"html" should replaced with "append"

Comment: @Musa , I know, but it should waits on the first iteration , because it takes a time to fadeOut. This is not happened !

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to add items to `$("#slider")` fade them out then replace them with new items, `.html()` does not wait for [`.fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/), you can use `.fadeOut()` callback to replace the items after fadeout.

```
function fadeFunc(){
    var i = $("#slider").data('current')+1;
    if (i < slidesArray.length){
        $("#slider").data('current', i);
        var linkHref = slidesArray[i][1];
        var imageSource = slidesArray[i][0];

        $("#slider").html(
            "<a href='" + linkHref + "'><img src='"+ imageSource + "'></a>")
            .fadeOut(5000, fadeFunc);            
    }
} 

$("#slider").data('current', 0)
    .html("<a href='" + slidesArray[0][1] + "'><img src='"+ slidesArray[0][0] + "'></a>")
    .fadeOut(5000, fadeFunc);
```